# Is it possible to load command files in spec.js files instead of support/index.js in cypress?

Tags: javascript, node.js, cypress, cypress-custom-commands

Right now whenever we write a new file that contains Cypress custom commands we add it using
Cypress.Commands.add()
and then import the file in support/index.js.

But my problem here is that I've 100 such Custom command files, and I cannot load every file everytime I run cypress, because this is going to cause memory issue soon or after

Instead is there a way to import the cypress custom command files in each testcase spec file itself (if needed) instead of support/index.js?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can import the commands individually in the spec where they are used, the syntax is the same as you are already using in `support/index.js`. I can't think of any reason why not.

This would only have an effect if you run the specs **individually**, obviously.

But I do not think it will cause much difference to the memory usage, since code files have a small footprint (compared to say fixture files).

Comment: The answer you gave will work only if the custom command is going to be used in that specific test case file alone. But if i have 200 test case files and need to use particular command in 50 of them but not the other 150, i have to write the command in all 50 test case files according to your answer. But I want to reduce that by writing the command only once but importing them only when I need them. Not import them in support/indes.js which loads every file even if I don't use it.

Answer (score -1):

I just found out that you can import the custom command file in your test script file as well

I just added

**import './customCommand.js'**

in my test script file and accessed the command as usual like

**cy.customCommand1();**

and it worked fine

Comment: You just told Rachel that doesn't work.

Comment: Rachel mentioned "You can import the commands individually" which means the cypress commands right? Maybe Rachel mentioned commands.js. My bad.